# Macchanger returns error but mac adress is changed

Tags: networking

Because I wanted to understand how my ISP is assigning the IP addresses to the different devices connected to the same router I first tried to change my IP with disconnecting from the network and reconnect to it.

Online I read that I might get a new IP address if I change the Mac address.

So I tried to change the Mac address using the following commands:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

$ sudo macchanger -m 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
```

what I got, was the following output:

> Current MAC:   aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (unknown)
>   Permanent MAC: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (unknown)
>   [ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too   many open files in system

But if I set the wifi adapter up again with:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

and then check for the mac adress with:

```
$ sudo macchanger wlan0
```

the output i got was:

> Current MAC:   00:11:22:33:44:55 (CIMSYS Inc)
>   Permanent MAC: 44:1c:a8:f9:bb:bd (unknown)

So apparently the mac address was changed even though I got an error message.

I know the mac address was definitely changed because I was also not able to connect to my wifi anymore (if I change back to the permanent one I can connect again).

Now my question:

**Can anybody tell me why I get an error message even though the mac address was changed?**

Thanks for your help and sorry if I didn't use the perfectly correct terms to describe everything. But I hope it is still understandable and else please ask and correct me.

Cheers, Baba Shrimp

First of all thanks a lot for your fast answer.

I checked for further information and found the Information for the Ethernet interface as well as for the wireless connection.

But to be honest I have no idea what I should do with this information now?

Then I checked out the website of `macchanger` where I could find the zipped `macchanger` version 1.6.0 as well as the `pgp signature` which belongs to it.

So I downloaded both and tried to check for it's integrity. I never used gpg before so I tried to read into it. I tried to verify the integrity with:

```
gpg --verify macchanger-1.6.0.tar.gz.sig  macchanger-1.6.0.tar.gz
```

Which resulted basically in:

> gpg: signature can not be verified: no public key.

So I started looking for the public key of `macchanger` but didn't even came close to find infos about where I can find the key. I found how to import a key. But how import a key if you don't know where to import it from?

`apt source macchanger` does not work because of the following ussue:

> Source package for macchanger can not be found

And for your last hint I don't even understand what `macchanger-1.7.0/src/netinfo.c`

should be. So I think it is not necessary to mention that I have idea what code underneath it means.

I can understand if you have no interest in answering all this questions. So maybe you could just give me a better hint where to start with my research if I just want to learn something about how networks work?

Thanks a lot

Baba Shrimp

Comment: You may or may not get a new public IP from the ISO if the router's MAC changes, not if the devices connected to it change theirs. So, you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a bug in `macchanger` with your particular hardware. The hardware accepted the change, but the reported status was misunderstood by `macchanger`.

`sudo lshw -C network` will show what hardware you're using, which driver, ...

`macchanger` has it's own web page: `http://www.gnu.org/software/macchanger`.

`apt source macchanger` will download the source, so you can see how it works.

The error message comes from `macchanger-1.7.0/src/netinfo.c`:

```
 85 mc_net_info_set_mac (net_info_t *net, const mac_t *mac)
 86 {
 87         int i;
 88 
 89         for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
 90                 net->dev.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i] = mac->byte[i];
 91         }
 92 
 93         if (ioctl(net->sock, SIOCSIFHWADDR, &net->dev) < 0) {
 94                 perror ("[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions");
 95                 return -1;
 96         }
 97 
 98         return 0;
 99 }
```